# Intranet site not accessible with www through Sonicwall VPN

Tags: vpn

we have a intranet site it is accessible in my internal network, where as when i connect through sonicwall VPN, it does not open, i try with the web server domain IP address it works.

with the name address the site does not open through VPN.

can any one help.

Answer (score 0):

That means that your computer is not using the DNS servers that are on the other side of the VPN for their lookups.

This is not something an end user can fix, it has to be fixed by the person who set up your companies VPN.